# Unity transform.LookAt in only one axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

I've been working on a game and it's going really nice. Got some help from here and I need it again. So I'm making a 2D top-down shooter and I need my enemy to look at the player, and obviously the enemy will rotate in all axis and thus being invincible or will look really weird. So, how do I make it rotate only in the Z axis ? Also if you are going to provide and answer I need it done in UnityScript.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity LookAt 2d Equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813825/unity-lookat-2d-equivalent)

Comment: Converting JS to C# and back isn't that hard, btw.  I highly recommend switching to C#, as 95% of the assets you'll find on the store or provided in various community locations will be C#.

Comment: I don't buy assets and the answer provided in the "Possible duplicate" didn't help

Comment: @NikolaZagorac That answer should directly help you. If not do it automatically, definitely provide the framework for it. Also, a lot of assets are free and what Draco18s was saying is that a lot of resources are written in C# instead of UnityScript.

Comment: Problem is I don't know C#. I've been learning only Java and then it was easy for me to learn JavaScript. But for me to learn C# I first must learn C, at least I have heard so.

Comment: Actually, C# and Java have a lot more in common than JavaScript does with Java. (The naming is horribly confusing in that respect, though). Mostly just little syntactical differences to keep in mind.

Comment: Also, you don't have to learn C first. In fact, my friend is a programming teacher and he teaches C# as a first language.

Comment: **Do not** use "unityscript" with Unity. it is deprecated and is going to be removed. Just use c# (in fact, far easier to use).

Comment: If you are learning Java, C# will be the most similar language available that you can use with Unity.

Comment: ok all of you are commenting how i should learn C#. Why doesn't anyone give me an answer to my question ? :/

Comment: I think it's because most people believe that the suggested duplicate adequately meets your needs. If the solutions offered in that question are not correct for your purposes, please provide additional detail to your question so we can better understand what your objective is.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set a fixed value at the axis that you don't want to move.

Example, LookAt moving only the Z axis:

```
var adjusted= target;
adjusted.x = 0;
adjusted.y = 0;
transform.LookAt(adjusted);
```

If you had made a quickly search on google, you would find it.

Answer (score 0):

put this in void update

`transform.lookAt(target, transform.forward);`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I believe this solution should work.

```
Transform Target; 
Quaternion TargetRot = transform.LookAt(Target.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(TargetRot.x,0,0);
```