# Unity - Find a point for a gameobject to look at the mouse while camera is at any angle

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I have a 3D game where I want an arrow to point in the direction base on the mouses angle of that object in a 2D view.

Now from the camera looking down at the board from a 90 degree x-angle standpoint it works fine.  The below image is when I am in a 90 Degree x-angle Camera angle facing down on my game and I have the arrow face where my cursor is:

[image]

But now when we take a step back and have the camera at a 45 degree x-angle the direction the arrow is facing is a bit off.  The below image is when I have the cursor face my mouse cursor when my camera is on a 45 degree x-angle :

[image]

Now lets look at the above image but when the Camera is shifted back to 90 Degrees x-angle:

[image]

My current code is:

```
        // Get the vectors of the 2 points, the pivot point which is the ball start and the position of the mouse.
        Vector2 objectPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(_arrowTransform.position);
        Vector2 mousePoint = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2( mousePoint.y - objectPoint.y, mousePoint.x - objectPoint.x ) * 180 / Mathf.PI;
        _arrowTransform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-angle, Vector2.up) * Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f);
```

What would I have to add in my Mathf.Atan2() to compensate for the camera rotation on the x and/or y to make sure when the user wants to move the camera how they please it will make sure to provide an accurate direction?

EDIT : The solution was in MotoSV's answer with using Plane.  This allowed me to get the exact point no matter what my camera angles were based on my mouse position. Code that worked for me is below :

```
    void Update()
    {
        Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, new Vector3(_arrowTransform.position.x, _arrowTransform.position.y, _arrowTransform.position.z));
        Ray ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float distance;
        if (groundPlane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
        {
            Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(distance);
            _arrowTransform.LookAt(point);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116555/aiming-direction-using-mouse/116561#116561)

Comment: Why not just use **LookAt** ????????????  Note, in general **never use quaternions**.  Simply use Rotate.  This is a huge point of confusion in Unity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity transform.LookAt in only one axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348520/unity-transform-lookat-in-only-one-axis)

Comment: @JoeBlow It isn't a duplicate.  I realized the title of my question wasn't the greatest but it is changed now and even so it would not of mattered if the question was understand just by looking at the pictures alone.  Thank you for the input though on not using Quaternions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this does not answer your question directly with regards to the `Mathf.Atan2` method it is a alternative approach that may be useful.

This would be placed onto the game object that represents the arrow:

```
public class MouseController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera _camera;

    private void Start()
    {
        _camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, this.transform.position);
        Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float distance;
        Vector3 axis = Vector3.zero;

        if(groundPlane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
        {
            Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(distance);
            axis = (point - this.transform.position).normalized;
            axis = new Vector3(axis.x, 0f, axis.z);
        }

        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(axis);
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to:

1. Create a `Plane` instance centred at the game object's position
2. Convert the mouse screen position into a `Ray` that heads into the world
   relative to the camer'a current position and rotation
3. Then cast that ray onto the `Plane` created in step #1
4. If the ray intersects the plane, then you can use the `GetPoint` method to find out where on the plane the ray hit
5. Then create a direction vector from the centre of the plane to the intersect point and create a `LookRotation` based on the vector

You can find out more information about the `Plane` class on the [Unity - Plane](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) documentation page.

Comment: Once again you come to my rescue on a question MotoSV, TY!  The Plane solution is so simple and clean and it allows me to use other built in functions such as LookAt() so I don't have to go into any trigonometry.